# Kubernetes: Reference Previously-Defined ConfigMap key-value pair

Tags: docker, kubernetes

## TL;DR

> Can I reference a previously-defined key-value pair in a ConfigMap?

## Full Version

I'm writing a deployment specification for an application which accepts
its configuration from environment variables at startup. Some of the
environment variables are derived from others. If I were setting
them up as file to be sourced at application startup, I would simply
do:

```
[me@myserver ~]$ cat ./myenv.sh
export FOO=foo
export BAR=bar
export FOOBAR=$FOO$BAR
[me@myserver ~]$ . ./myenv.sh
[me@myserver ~]$ printenv FOOBAR
foobar
```

However, the analagous way to do this in a ConfigMap by referencing
previously-defined key-value pairs doesn't work (see sample ConfigMap
and Pod, below). Here are the results:

```
[me@myserver ~]$ kubectl create -f my-app-config.yaml -f my-app-pod.yaml
configmap "my-app" created
pod "my-app" created
[me@myserver ~]$ kubectl exec -it my-app -- printenv | grep MY_CONFIGMAP
MY_CONFIGMAP_FOO=foo
MY_CONFIGMAP_FOOBAR=$(MY_CONFIGMAP_FOO)$(MY_CONFIGMAP_BAR)
MY_CONFIGMAP_BAR=bar
```

Hoped-for value of `MY_CONFIGMAP_FOOBAR` is `foobar`.

I attempted to cross-apply the following instructions under
[Use ConfigMap-defined environment variables in Pod commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#use-configmap-defined-environment-variables-in-pod-commands)
from the documentation:

> You can use ConfigMap-defined environment variables in the **`command`**
> section of the Pod specification using the **`$(VAR_NAME)`**
> Kubernetes substitution syntax.

However, this obviously did not work, and I've been unable to find an
answer in my research.

I suspect I already know the answer, but is there any way to accomplish
this?

## [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

### ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-app

data:
  MY_CONFIGMAP_FOO: foo
  MY_CONFIGMAP_BAR: bar
  
  # Desired concatenation would be `foobar`
  MY_CONFIGMAP_FOOBAR: $(MY_CONFIGMAP_FOO)$(MY_CONFIGMAP_BAR)
```

### Pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app

spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: alpine
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: my-app
          
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      
    args:
      - -c
      - "while true; do sleep 3600; done"
```

## Epilogue: Twenty-Nine Months Later

After working with Kubernetes for an additional two-and-a-half years, my ultimate solution (and recommendation) is to use a Helm chart, preferrably with an Ansible-managed deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your expected result with help of this tool: [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html).

Create the `ConfigMap` following way,

```
envsubst < my-app-config.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Now, all environment variables on your `ConfigMap` will be replaced with resolved value.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but better than expected. But unless someone gives an answer which relies solely on Kubernetes, I will certainly accept it.

Comment: This also works. `You can use ConfigMap-defined environment variables in the command section of the Pod specification using the $(VAR_NAME) Kubernetes substitution syntax.` What problem are you facing here?

Comment: Indeed. I even cited that in my initial question. ;-) The issue I'm trying to solve is that the application uses various environment variables both separately and combined together, but when they're combined together, it expects them to be combined into a third environment variable. I.e., it uses variables `FOO` and `BAR` both separately and combined together as variable `FOOBAR`. It would be convenient and less prone to error to be able to derive `FOOBAR` from `FOO` and `BAR`.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation is to use `kind: Deployment`
Combining variables works fine in that config file.  I haven't tried pods directly.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: MY_CONFIGMAP_FOOBAR
          value: $(MY_CONFIGMAP_FOO)$(MY_CONFIGMAP_BAR)
```